# CSS Как сделать прокрутку внутри блока при body(CSS: overflow: hidden)?

Tags: html, css, прокрутка, hidden

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 1500px;
}
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.child {
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap hide">
 <div class="child">
</div>
```

Т.е у body контент скрыт, но внутренний контент wrap, не скроллится. Подскажите мне решение

Comment: нужно задать высоту для `.wrap`, например 100%

Comment: @fanfer не помогло :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментарии Вам правильно указали - задать вертикальный размер (высоту):

```
.wrap { height: 100%; }
```

или

```
.wrap { height: 100vh; }
```

В противном случае, содержимое будет растягивать блок, а следовательно и скролл появляться не будет.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.child {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap hide">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```